# Why does google chrome show the FILE CHOOSER on the CONSOLE even when DISPLAY X11 FORWARDING is on?

Tags: firefox, xorg, google-chrome, sshd, x11-forwarding

I have ssh'ed from `machine1` to another machine  (`machine2`)

```
machine1:$ ssh -X user@machine2

machine2: gedit
```

and I run gedit and I open the file chooser.

Both gedit and the file chooser respect the DISPLAY setting.

AND SHOW on `machine1`'s DISPLAY.

THIS IS EXPECTED.

This is GEDIT:

[image: gedit]

When you use FILE->OPEN you see:

[image: file chooser]

But why does `google-chrome` and `firefox` always seem to show the file chooser on the console of `machine2`

Of course the reason I ssh'ed to `machine2` is that I am not at `machine2` console.  I cannot see the file chooser because I am remote.

It seems that it is specific to some programs because `gedit` does work correctly.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? Recent versions have dropped X11 in favor of Wayland so X forwarding won't work reliably there